# Best way to *invalidate* a checksum

Tags: checksum, invalidation, crc32

Let's say that I have a 4KB buffer that contains at the start a checksum. This buffer contains metadata that references other buffers. N.B. the buffers are memory mapped files. I notice that one of the buffers are invalid (either the checksum does not work out OR the checksum is fine but it references an invalid buffer). Now, I want to invalidate the buffer that references another invalid buffer. What is the mathematically best way to invalidate the buffer? Corrupt the checksum itself so that it might not match up with the data OR corrupt the data so it might not match up with the checksum. Or is there a third, better way altogether? For what its worth, this is a CRC32 variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the CRC of your referencing buffer is valid, you can just simply subtract one from it, that will invalidate your buffer just fine. From your description, this seems to be the case since you state that the *referenced* buffer is the one whose CRC may be wrong.

If the referencing CRC32 *wasn't* valid, the safest bet would be to calculate the CRC *then* subtract one. You need to know the correct CRC first because a random choice of CRC, whilst *unlikely* to be the correct one, still has a roughly one-in-four-billion chance of being right.

Changing the CRC seems like the safest option here. Short of doing a mathematical analysis of the CRC32 algorithm, there's no way to guarantee that a specific change to the data won't generate the *same* CRC value (since a large number of data sets may map to the same CRC).

However, it's a certainty that a *specific* data set will always generate the same CRC so, by changing the CRC to something else, you can be sure that the block will now be invalid.

Comment: The CRC32 algorithm guarantees that changing any combination of bits within a single run of 32 consecutive bits will yield a different CRC.  Indeed, one may pick any 32 consecutive bits, the 2^32 different combinations of bit flips one might perform will yield all 2^32 different CRC values.